# passing hiveconf to spark sql and a hql file

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark -sql with -I option to submit my hql file . I also want to pass in parameters to the hql file using --hiveconf / --hivevar . How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried looking at this link? https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2016/03/12/how-to-execute-hive-sql-file-in-spark-engine/

Comment: Yea tried that out . I am getting the error mentioned in this page.https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201503.mbox/%3CCACdk1M75GBWUo+N41WSpxgjRKytLV8PZ2uWi3SaMQodrG8LRGw@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: hi Balakumaran, is date_key a string or an integer type?

Comment: can you also run this and give us the contents of out.txt file?   spark-sql -f script.hql -hiveconf CUR_DATE=20150119 > out.txt 2>&1